# How to use vuex-flash message?

Tags: vue.js

I created a sample Vuex project and did the following steps to add [Vuex-Flash message](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-flash) to the project:

```
$ npm install --save vuex-flash
```

in main.js:

```
import VuexFlash from 'vuex-flash';
Vue.use(VuexFlash, { mixin: true });
```

in store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { createFlashStore } from 'vuex-flash';

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    title: 'My Custom Title'
  },
  plugins: [
    createFlashStore()
  ]  
})
```

in a component:

```
methods: {
  test: function () {
    this.flash({ message: 'some message', variant: 'success' });
  }
}
```

but when I call test() nothing happens. What did I miss or do wrong?